# JS: access image height after pulling it from an array

Tags: javascript

I've populated an array of images as seen here

```
$($target + " img").each(function() {
    images.push(this);
});
```

I then want to access the first image in this array, specifically it's height

```
this.begin = function() {
    var first = images[0];
};
```

However, when I try to access `first.height` and/or `first.clientHeight`, it's 0.

When I `console.log(first);` I get: `<img src="img/1.jpg" class="sluider-img">`.

When I `console.log(images)` I get: `[img.sluider-img, img.sluider-img, img.sluider-img, img.sluider-img]`.

I can see that the target has a height / clientHeight by looking through the array seen in the above line.

Any reason I can't access the height of this element when I fetch it from the array, however I can see it while it's in the array?

I'm trying to access the height as follows

```
this.begin = function() {
    var first = images[0];
    console.log(first.clientHeight);
};
```

If so, how? Cheers guys.

EDIT:

When I console.log `images` array:

```
... className: "sluider-img"clientHeight: 647clientLeft: 0clientTop: 0clientWidth: 1478
... // repeat for each image element
```

When I console.log `images[0]`:

```
<img src="img/1.jpg" class="sluider-img">
```

When I do the following:

```
images.forEach(function(image) {
     console.log(image);
});

>>
<img src="img/1.jpg" class="sluider-img">
<img src="img/2.jpg" class="sluider-img">
<img src="img/3.jpg" class="sluider-img">
<img src="img/4.jpg" class="sluider-img">
```

When I do the following:

```
images.forEach(function(image) {
    console.log(image);
});
console.log(images); // this is new?

>>
sluider.js:37 img.sluider-img
sluider.js:37 img.sluider-img
sluider.js:37 img.sluider-img
sluider.js:37 img.sluider-img (it gets the image classes)
```

My full code

```
    images = [];
    prepare_image = function(image) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("src", image);
        img.setAttribute("class", "sluider-img");
        element.appendChild(img);
    };

    this.initialize = function(settings) {

        /* creates the images and adds them into the
        sluider container */

        settings.images.forEach(function(image) {
            this.prepare_image(image);
        });

        $(".sluider-img").each(function() {
            images.push(this);
        });
    };

    this.begin = function() {
        /* at this point I need to get the height
        of the tallest image so I can base the
        container off of that. */
        console.log(images);
    };
```

And

```
var sluider = $($target).sluider().data($plugin);
sluider.initialize(
    {
        title: "TITLE",
        target: $target,
        images: [
            "img/1.jpg",
            "img/2.jpg",
            "img/3.jpg",
            "img/4.jpg"
        ]
    }
);
sluider.begin();
```

Comment: How are you trying to access the height? Please show code example

Comment: Is image loaded when you are accessing its height?

Comment: yes @lubkl, if I console.log the images array I see it stored in there, when I try and access an element in that array, I can't access it.

Comment: .height is not a function @Shahar

Comment: I don't get it, why is that `images[0]` returns `<img src="img/1.jpg" class="sluider-img">` while your `images` array contains only the class of the `img`

Comment: I have no idea @JohnroePauloCañamaque, when I log the array of images I see all attributes of the image class, then I get a HTMLCollection when I access it from the array directly.

Comment: Some images really have height zero. Check other images as well. try change the image's height and then run it again, does the height updates (after you set the array again)?

Comment: I insist that images are not loaded, your code looks correct for e.g. try to run it in console on stackoverflow page: var images=[];$("img").each(function() {images.push(this);});images[0].height; you will get height of first found image

Comment: @lubki they're loaded, I have no doubt for that, as I can see them all loaded if I log the `images` array (I made a change to the question with more information)

Comment: @Jackhardcastle for jquery objects height is a function

Comment: Ok, so when you write images[0].height in console it also returns 0?

Comment: If I sit refreshing the page, half the time it will give me the HTMLCollection and half the time it will give me the class collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about checking if image was loaded?

```
var first = images[0];
if(first.complete){
    console.log(first.height);
}else{
   first.onload=function(){console.log(first.height);}
}
```

Comment: Perfect, this works - thank you!

Although, still would love to know what was causing the random result fluctuations.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the **EXACT** scenario, but here is my answer based on understanding.

```
var images = [];
$.each($('.sluider-img'), function(i,d){
    images.push(d);
});

var first = images[0];

var height = first.clientHeight;
alert(height);
```

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fwznyrk8/)

Basically, what you are doing is right, it is just that maybe you are not getting the value itself because of the way you are accessing the array and the value that you need (maybe because of the function that you created or you are not calling function `begin`)

Comment: Hi, your example works for me, I implemented this but I still get the HTMLCollection 50% of the time upon refresh, kinda hit and miss - I should mention at this point that I'm loading the images via javascript, before this call.

My code is encased in a ready() function, however - there may be a chance that the images haven't correctly loaded when I make this call? Even though I make the call after I've loaded the images onto the document. 

Is there a ready function, or an alternative for this case?

Comment: It is inside a ready function - but I'm dynamically adding the images after it's checked the whether the DOM is ready.

Comment: How do you add those image dynamically? Might as well put that in your question so that it would be clearer to others

Comment: Added into my question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the same and i obtain some interesting results:

```
var images = []; 
$('.sluider-img img').each(function(){
    images.push(this) 
});
console.log(images[0]);
console.log(images[0].clientHeight + " " + $(images[0]).height());
```

By executing the same code 20 times on Chrome I obtain, on the same image, sometimes:

0 0 (wrong)

others:

220 220 (correct heights)

Images are loaded and the code results are correct or wrong in random order.
Unfortunately I can't explain the source of this problem, but probably is the source of your frustration..
(sorry, I meant to comment but I can't because of low reputation)

Comment: It's a real nail-biter this one!